# Download Multiple Lists of URLs Using Wget (Win) & Convert *.txt LineEndings to "CRLF" (Unix Format)

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, wget

I've 3 text files, each one of them has a list of about 250 *.Png URLs (one url for every line), and they're located in
different SubDirectory (so I can download every list into its own folder) .

I've made this batch command for the whole process :-

```
For /R %%F in ("*.txt") do wget -i "%%F"
```

but I don't know why it gives me an output like this :-

```
http://website.com/images/file1.png%0dhttp://website.com/images/file2.png%0dhttp://website.com/images/file3.png%0d....http://website.com/images/file250.png
```

I tried to keep one URL only in each text file and deleted the rest, then I started the batch .

This time It worked, but with a little bug ! all of the three *.Png files, have been downloaded,
into the main directory, not in the Sub-Directories as I was planning .

So, What am I supposed to do to fix this,

I just need to download every text list, inside its own directory .

Any Help Please..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an encoding issue.

You don't say where you got wget.exe (it doesn't ship with Windows), but I guess it's one of the UNIX utilities.  UNIX uses LF (%0a) exclusively for linefeeds.  From the output above, your file is using either a bare CR (%0d) or a Windows CRLF (%0d%0a), and wget isn't recognizing them as line breaks.

To tell the difference, try to open the file in notepad.exe.  If it looks normal, it's CRLF (and your wget just can't handle Windows-style txt files).  If the lines are all squished together, it's a bare CR and whatever is generating your text files is doing it wrong.

Either way, the solution to the encoding issue is to put the text file into a format that wget can understand.  Ideally, you should fix whatever is generating the text file.  If not, you will need to convert the text file before use.  For example, using the .NET framework's encoding support (via Powershell, on Vista and above)

```
powershell -ex unrestricted -command "get-content foo.txt | set-content foo1.txt -Encoding UTF8"
```

Another option is to change out wget for something that can handle the different encoding.  Powershell's Invoke-Webrequest can help here (it even aliases to 'wget')

```
powershell -ex unrestricted -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '%uri%' -OutFile '%localfilename%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your Reply,
Your expectation is absolutely right, and Here is What I Did,

First of All, Allow me to remind You that I had 2 questions :-

### 1-Fixing The "%0d" issue (Line Breaks):

I've two solutions for this:-

A:- By Using NotePad++

- Open The URLs List File in Notepad++
- Press on "Edit" Menu > EOL Conversion
- Choose "Unix/OSX Format"
- Done

B:- By Using The GNUWin32 Tool "Dos2Unix" Command :-

```
For /R %%a in ("*.txt") do "Dos2Unix" -c mac %%a
```

Note.1 This command is going to convert all the *.txt files in the current Directory and Sub-Directories, from "Mac!!!", to "Unix" line endings .

Note.2 I know that, as a windows user, I was supposed to use **-c ascii** instead of **-c Mac** , 
       in order to convert from "Dos" to "Unix" line endings , But I don't know why it didn't work for me, and "-c Mac" did !!!

### 2-Downloadine each list inside its own sub-directory:-

This one, I've made an alternative solution for it,

By Modifying the batch command, using the **WGet** Switch **-p** :-

```
For /R %%F in ("*.txt") do wget -p -i "%%F"
```

Note. The **-p** Switch, Used For downloading files, inside its own directories,
      Based on their locations in the website .
So, If you've 2 lists of URLs . and their addresses were :

http://website.com/images_png/file(n).png

http://website.com/images_jpg/file(n).jpg

Then, the download location is gonna be :-

- X:\WorkingDirectory\website\images_png\
- X:\WorkingDirectory\website\images_jpg\

---

Thank you again **Ryan** for your help, I'm so grateful to you